# Insert Order to MS Access from VB6

Tags: ms-access, vb6

i got one of our old VB application for training management.It was written in VB6 and the database is MsAccess.
When im using that application, while saving the training sessions ,all records are saved in between the previous records(not in order). It is not get added in last row. And also the application fetching the data from database and showed it in gridview. So the final display is in unsorted way.Like latest data which i was added using form,displaying in some where in middle row.
When i see the database table, all new data were get added in middle rows.
Here i will show the code:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO TrAssignment (BatchID,Category,CourseNumber,CourseTitle,FromDate,ToDate,Duration,Location, Trainer, FixedCost,DefaultStudentCost) VALUES ('" & CStr(txtBatchid.Text) & "','" & CStr(cmbCrscategory) & "','" & CStr(sCourNo) & "', '" & CStr(sCourTitle) & "','" & SchfromDTPick.Value & "','" & SchtoDTPicker.Value & "','" & CStr(txtSchduration.Text) & "','" & cmbLocation & "','" & CStr(cmbTrainer) & "','" & CStr(Trim(txtFixedcost.Text)) & "','" & CStr(Trim(txtDefault.Text)) & "')"
                rs.Open sql, conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
```

And also the date format in form is  like dd-mm-yyyy,for some records the date get saved in this exact format. But for some, the date format is like d/m/yyyy. 
Just they are fetching the date from the date control,no formatting in code.

Answer (score 1):

Your date format is wrong. In general, you could benefit from this function:

```
' Converts a value of any type to its string representation.
' The function can be concatenated into an SQL expression as is
' without any delimiters or leading/trailing white-space.
'
' Examples:
'   SQL = "Select * From TableTest Where [Amount]>" & CSql(12.5) & "And [DueDate]<" & CSql(Date) & ""
'   SQL -> Select * From TableTest Where [Amount]> 12.5 And [DueDate]< #2016/01/30 00:00:00#
'
'   SQL = "Insert Into TableTest ( [Street] ) Values (" & CSql(" ") & ")"
'   SQL -> Insert Into TableTest ( [Street] ) Values ( Null )
'
' Trims text variables for leading/trailing Space and secures single quotes.
' Replaces zero length strings with Null.
' Formats date/time variables as safe string expressions.
' Uses Str to format decimal values to string expressions.
' Returns Null for values that cannot be expressed with a string expression.
'
' 2016-01-30. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function CSql( _
    ByVal Value As Variant) _
    As String

    Const vbLongLong    As Integer = 20
    Const SqlNull       As String = " Null"

    Dim Sql             As String
    Dim LongLong        As Integer

    #If Win32 Then
        LongLong = vbLongLong
    #End If
    #If Win64 Then
        LongLong = VBA.vbLongLong
    #End If

    Select Case VarType(Value)
        Case vbEmpty            '    0  Empty (uninitialized).
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbNull             '    1  Null (no valid data).
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbInteger          '    2  Integer.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbLong             '    3  Long integer.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbSingle           '    4  Single-precision floating-point number.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbDouble           '    5  Double-precision floating-point number.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbCurrency         '    6  Currency.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbDate             '    7  Date.
            Sql = Format(Value, " \#yyyy\/mm\/dd hh\:nn\:ss\#")
        Case vbString           '    8  String.
            Sql = Replace(Trim(Value), "'", "''")
            If Sql = "" Then
                Sql = SqlNull
            Else
                Sql = " '" & Sql & "'"
            End If
        Case vbObject           '    9  Object.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbError            '   10  Error.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbBoolean          '   11  Boolean.
            Sql = Str(Abs(Value))
        Case vbVariant          '   12  Variant (used only with arrays of variants).
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbDataObject       '   13  A data access object.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbDecimal          '   14  Decimal.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbByte             '   17  Byte.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case LongLong           '   20  LongLong integer (Valid on 64-bit platforms only).
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbUserDefinedType  '   36  Variants that contain user-defined types.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbArray            ' 8192  Array.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case Else               '       Should not happen.
            Sql = SqlNull
    End Select

    CSql = Sql & " "

End Function
```