# Globalization in MS-ACCESS 2007

Tags: ms-access, globalization

What do I need to do to ensure application MS-ACCESS application will run correctly in different countries using MS-Access 2007?

Does MS-Access rely on MS-Windows country settings to determine the currency symbol, date formats, etc. automatically?

Thanks.

Edit

After some research, I came with the following links:

[Link 1-International Dates in Access](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html)

[Link 2-Add and customize date and time formats](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-and-customize-date-and-time-formats-763b9b04-ccf8-46a8-9ee3-6d8f6fb9e2f8)

Answer (score 0):

All you need is solid programming where you take nothing for granted.

You'll find much sloppy code - VBA and SQL - that is very US-centric, thus will fail in most non-US environments.

And yes, the UI settings of Access are controlled by default by Windows. You can override many of these if you have to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not sure which parts are handled by MS-Access and which parts the code needs to take care of?

Comment: It's you that need to take of the code. Access will do the rest.

Comment: For example, the system is developed in USA but it will be used in Spain. What do you need to tell the programmer to take care of? The same code may have to be run in U.K. also.

Comment: It's mostly criteria strings for filtering or in concatenated SQL. If you have such, you may take advantage of my [CSql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996045/insert-order-to-ms-access-from-vb6/36997461#36997461) function.